# How do you extract the value from multiple variants of a custom type?

Tags: pattern-matching, elm, algebraic-data-types

I have a type like,

```
type Post 
    = Blog String String
    | Announcement String String
```

And a function like,

```
upcaseTitle : Post -> Post
upcaseTitle post =
    case post of
        Blog title body ->
            { post | title = String.toUpper title }
        Announcement title body ->
            { post | title = String.toUpper title }
```

I would like to write code like,

```
upcaseTitle : Post -> Post
upcaseTitle post =
    case post of
        Post title body ->
            { post | title = String.toUpper title }
```

I want to add one clause in my `case` statement that matches all `Post` types and extracts the common `String`, `title`, since it is shared across all variations of my union type.

Is this possible in elm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, not possible. In a few other languages this can be achieved using or-patterns (even then you still have to enumerate and deconstruct every variant, but they can share a single body), but Elm aims to be a simpler language than those.

One option is to extract the common branch body into a function:

```elm
upcaseTitle : Post -> Post
upcaseTitle post =
    let
        setTitle title =
            { post | title = String.toUpper title }
    in
    case post of
        Blog title body ->
            setTitle title

        Announcement title body ->
            setTitle title
```

Another is to define a separate function to extract just the title:

```elm
getTitle : Post -> String
getTitle post =
    case post of
        Blog title body ->
            title

        Announcement title body ->
            title

upcaseTitle : Post -> Post
upcaseTitle post =
    { post | title = String.toUpper (getTitle post) }
```

But if every variant of your custom type is identical, I'd start by questioning the design of that type. Maybe it would be better to use a record where the post type is just a field instead?

```elm
type PostType
    = Blog
    | Announcement

type Post =
    { title : String
    , body : String
    , postType : PostType
    }
```